# Keyword not supported: ´username´

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting, connection-string, stimulsoft

Strange error here, while compiling a report using Stimulsoft I'm getting this error, but it has nothing to do with my connection string which is like this:

```
Data Source=server\instance;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True
```

There is no username ever in that connection so I really have no idea why this is happening, any ideas?

Comment: No ideas, no. Can you show us the code for your report, maybe, and what line the error points at?

Comment: The error sounds like it's looking in an sql statement, rather than connection string.

Comment: Yes, really strange. I cannot even see what is the error

Comment: @AaronBertrand It doesn't point to any errors in the code actually, the error is only brought up by stimulsoft when the report compiles, and about the code that's what confuses me as well, I actually searched through the code of the application and it never ever mentions the word username, so I really have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Well, have you talked to stimulsoft support? Sorry, I have absolutely no idea what that software is.

Comment: I posted the question at their forum yes, but they are on the other side of the world and only seem to answer once a day so it takes some time to get an answer..

Comment: Did you try to Test connection in the SQL Connection window?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your data source used for the report. It might happened that connection string is hard coded somewhere in the code or data source.

Comment: Yeah I did think about this as well, since there is no mention of any username, or even user id on the connection string, it may have been added manually through the code, but the word doesn't even appear on the whole source code available, I searched the solution as a whole and nothing.